# Update all using jquery

Tags: jquery

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshmonster/namVk/1/). When i click the 2nd img then click next, it doesn't update. I want update the both next() and img at the same time. Is this possible ?

Html:

```
<div class="myclass selected">
Content 1
</div>
<div class="myclass">
Content 2
</div>
<div class="myclass">
Content 3
</div>

<ul>
  <li><img src="http://www.lillehammer.com/ImageVault/Images/id_2122/scope_66/ImageVaultHandler.aspx" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d7/Valued_image_seal.svg/40px-Valued_image_seal.svg.png" /></li>
  <li><img src="http://www.iconico.com/i/icoImageFilterPro100.gif" /></li>
</ul>

<a class="next">next</a>
```

​
css:

```
.myclass {display:none;}


img {height: 20px; width: 20px; position: relative; display: block; margin: 20px; float: left;}
​
```

javascript:

```
$('img', 'ul').on('click', function() {
    $(".myclass").eq($(this).parent('li').index()).show()
                 .siblings('div').hide();
});

$('.selected').show();

$(".next").click(function(){
    var selected = $('.selected');
    selected.removeClass('selected');
    selected.hide();
    
    var next = selected.next(".myclass");
    if(next.length === 0) {
        next = $(".myclass").first();
    }
    next.addClass('selected');
    next.show();
   
});
```

Comment: Explain better your goal

Comment: click 2nd image, it show "content 2", then click the next, it doesn't show the "content 3". So i want to show the next if i did the above order. Sorry for my bad vague questions.

Comment: Not only in chrome. I tried in firefox too and got same problem. Is there any solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img', 'ul').on('click', function() {
    $(".myclass").eq($(this).parent('li').index()).show()
                 .siblings('div').hide();
});

$('.selected').show();

$(".next").click(function(){
    if ($('.myclass:visible').length) {
        var curr = $('.myclass:visible'),
            next = curr.next('.myclass').length?curr.next('.myclass'):$('.myclass').first();

        curr.hide();
        next.show();
    }else{
        $('.myclass').first().show();
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/namVk/2/)
    ​

Comment: Is this possible to show the "content 1" when load at initial ?

Comment: well thanks, i did that. i didn't check the .selected. Thanks for your answers

Comment: @user1621335 - sure, just add `$('.myclass').first().show();` at the start of the script. Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/namVk/7/), and I added the selected class if for some reason you need it for something else?

Answer (score 0):

seems you wanted this:

```
$('img', 'ul').on('click', function() {
    $(".myclass").eq($(this).parent('li').index()).addClass('selected').show()
                 .siblings('div').hide();
});

$('.selected').show();

$(".next").click(function(){
    var selected = $('.selected');
    selected.removeClass('selected');
    selected.hide();
    
    var next = selected.next(".myclass");
    if(next.length === 0) {
        next = $(".myclass").first();
    }
    next.addClass('selected');
    next.show();
   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/namVk/6/

Comment: Seems to me that's almost exactly what the OP posted, with the exact same problems ?